# Showing a Set is Saturated with Respect to a Given Function

Tags: general-topology

Let $q : [1,0) \cup [2,3] \rightarrow [0,2]$ be defined as $q(x) = x$ for $x \in [1,0)$ and $q(x) = x-1$ for $x \in [2,3]$. I am trying to show that $[2,3]$ is saturated with respect to the function $q$.

Let $y \in [0,2]$ and suppose that $q^{-1}(\{y\}) \cap [2,3]$. This implies $y$ is in $[1,2]$. Now, suppose that $x \in q^{-1}(\{y\})$. Then either $x$ is in $[0,1)$, in which case $q(x) = x = y \in [1,2]$, which is a contradiction, or $x$ is in $[2,3]$, in which case $q(x) = x-1=y$ which implies $x = y + 1 \in [1,3]$...

This is where I got stuck. I am trying to conclude that $q^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a subset of $[2,3]$.

**EDIT:** Shoot! I may have made an arithmetic error. The last line should read "in which case $q(x) = x-1=y$ which implies $x = y + 1 \in \color{red}{[2,3]}$..." At any rate, my argument appears circular for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that if $q^{-1}(\{y\})\cap [2,3]\ne\emptyset$, then $q^{-1}(\{y\})\subset [2,3]$. Since the map $q$ is one-to-one, there is not much to show. If $x\in q^{-1}(y)\cap [2,3]$, then $q(x)=y+1$ and, in fact, $\{x\}=q^{-1}(\{y\})\subset [2,3]$, as required.